# Actor Has Tag is returning false for my comparison

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to check for an actor's tag, "object", but the function is always returning false. I am using LineTrace to check actor's info, object names for instance are return good. I will put a link to a couple of screenshots of my blueprints.

https://ibb.co/H2R5S5y
https://ibb.co/xqTvmLb

Any help would be appreciated, if you need more info I will happily provide it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the tag in the `Component Tags` but checking for the tag in `Hit Actor`.

You can either set the tag in `Actor`(by clicking the row above the root component and below the +Add Component) in the blueprint, and check for the tag in `Hit Actor`.

Or

Set the tag in `Component Tags` and check the tag in `Hit Component`

Comment: Thanks! just what I needed